# UIDocument couldn't close again?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsexception, uidocument

When a UIDocument is closed, can it close again?  Even when it's documentState is UIDocumentStateNormal after reopened?

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

```
[document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {

        [document closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {

                [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                    if (success) {

                        NSLog(@"%d", document.documentState);

                        //Exception
                        [document closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                            if (success) {
                            } 
                        }];
                    } 
                }];
            } 
        }];
    } 
}];
```

When closeWithCompletionHandler called at the "Exception" mark, an exception is thrown:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'closeWithCompletionHandler called while document is already closing'
```

Comment: Me too facing same issue, though I have used different UiDocument objects ,the overlapping of open or close is causing the random  NSInternalInconsistencyException crashes such as attempting to revert a document when it is closed.And also open doc ,close doc completion handlers nevre gets executes sometime.how to resolve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you are still inside the first `closeWithCompletionHandler` method when you call the second. By reading the exception that seems to be the cause.

Comment: But I think "CompletionHandler" means a callback when the method is complete, isn't it? In fact, this code is the a simplify example of my situation.

Comment: When I call the 2rd     closeWithCompletionHandler     method at other place where documentState is UIDocumentStateNormal , the same exception still.

Comment: You're right, but by the exception it seems that it isn't in a ready state. Try wrapping the 2nd call to openWithCompletionHandler in a NSInvocation and do a performSelector:AfterDelay: on the invoke method.

Comment: [document performSelector:@selector(closeWithCompletionHandler:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];

Comment: I find the problem. The path which the document save to is not the app's "Documents" directory. I set the document path is "Library/Application Support/Documents" just like the Apple Numbers did. It may cause some authority problem. Thank you very mush!

Comment: oh, wait for a moment. i am not sure. the different versions makes some confuse.

Comment: I make a misstake, authority problem is not the answer.

I think this code which works well answer the question: UIDocument can't close twice.

Comment: NSURL*fileURL=document.fileURL;
MyDocument*documentA=[[MyDocumentalloc]initWithFileURL:fileURL];
[documentAopenWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOLsuccess){
if(success){
[documentAcloseWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOLsuccess){
if(success){
MindMapDocument*documentB=[[MyDocumentalloc]initWithFileURL:fileURL];
[documentBopenWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOLsuccess){
if(success){
[documentBcloseWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOLsuccess){
if(success){
}
[documentBrelease];
}];
}
}];
[documentArelease];
}
}];
}
}];

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can only close a UIManagedDocument once per instatiation.

I had this problem, and solved it by, instead of re-opening the same document, I created a new one with the same data (using a custom initWith... method).

Then you can "re-close" the new instance of the document.

Keep in mind, the new instance of the document will have a new managed object context, so you probably should not try to use managed objects from the original document.  Re-fetch them in the new instance if needed.

Comment: This is true, but seems to have been fixed in iOS 6. Danger, test your apps on an iOS 5 device as well or you will not find this problem!!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and removing the second close solved it for me. I find as long as I use a separate UIManagedDocument instance for the second open/close, I don't get this error.

Also, I found I did not get the error consistently in previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing documents is an Async activity (meaning it does it on another thread in the background).  By doing the opens and closes so close to one another you are overstepping the other process.  Make sure the other thread is finished before you do the next step (an open or a close).